# Use Get/POST requests to auto-fill a web form?

Tags: html

I was wondering if ti was possible to fill in webforms automatically with GET and POST requests? ive tried searching online but i couldnt find anything useful. Im planning on using autohotkey to send a URL with post requests embedded into it to fill in the forms. Is this possible? THanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is receiving the GET/POST requests? Is it a program you're writing? In what language? What are the forms you need to fill out based on that request? The short answer is yes it's possible, the long answer is much longer depending on your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to achieve is to fetch values of GET & POST data, and fill in the form right? There are several ways to do it. The following is by **PHP** ( you can do it with JavaScript too )

First, get the value from $_POST or $_GET :

```
$myname = $_POST['txt_name'];
```

Then, set the value of your form element, say, a text box:

```
<input type="text" name="txt_name" value="<?php echo $myname; ?>" />
```

That's it.

---

Furthermore, to send a form request via key, you can look into JavaScript function `onkeydown()` & `this.form.submit();`

---

Further furthermore, if you want a hidden form, just put every POST or GET data in `<input type="hidden">` tags.